# How do I fix paths after implementing Url-routing (ASP.NET 4.0 webforms)

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing, ashx, absolute-path

I have `route.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");` in my global.

Im using ResolveUrl in my  to point to my .js and .css files

All my links are generated with GetRouteUrl

BUT

None of my images are working. All my images is from a "ResizeHandler" .ashx file:
`<img src='ResizeHandler.ashx?file={0}&width=320&height=160' />`

Do I somehow ignore .ashx files in my global routes, or do I somehow use Server.MapPath, PhysicalApplicationPath or something else? What the best solution? Ive tried `src="/ResizeHa...` (note the "/") - doesnt work. It skips the project folder back to localhost:666/ResizeHandler.ashx.

-Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the Global.asax file I put this:

```
void RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.Ignore("{resource}.ashx/{*pathInfo}");

    // Register a route for someurl/{somename}
    // Other code here !
}
```

Work's fine for me in my personal experience; I hope the same for you.